# npm install mongoose: shasums.txt missing

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm

I'm trying to install Mongoose but it fails.

```
npm install mongoose --save
```

This is the error:

```
> kerberos@0.0.15 install D:\Hans\Playground\MultiVision\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)
D:\Hans\Playground\MultiVision\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos>node "c:\Dev\nodist\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node-v4.2.1.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node-v4.2.1.tar.gz
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/SHASUMS.txt
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/SHASUMS.txt
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/x64/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/x64/node.lib
gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node.lib
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/SHASUMS.txt
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/x64/node.lib
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/SHASUMS.txt
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/x64/node.lib
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node.lib
gyp http 404 http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node.lib
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 status code downloading SHASUMS.txt
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (c:\Dev\nodist\bin\node_module\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:316:18)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onResponse (c:\Dev\nodist\bin\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:832:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:415:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:88:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "c:\\dev\\nodist\\v-x64\\nodev4.2.1\\node.exe" "c:\\Dev\\nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Hans\Playground\MultiVision\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

It seems that gyp is looking in the right place but somehow expects the wrong files...

http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.1.2/ => SHASUMS256.txt

http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/ => SHASUMS.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of the 4.x branch of Node, the checksum file-naming conventions changed, and a SHASUMS256.txt file was retroactively added to repositories for older distributions in order to maintain backwards compatibility. However the SHASUMS.txt file was dropped, the result being that post-Node-4.x versions of NPM are able to work properly with old versions of Node, but pre-Node-4.x versions of NPM produce 404 errors while working with newer versions of Node.

Long story short, update your NPM instance to a version released with or after Node 4, e.g. the latest version:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```